# How to get a list from a SQL server using sqlcontext in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

i'm currently maintaining a C# based back end system and i'm in need to get a list of objects from the sql server from a simple id, but the entire system is done through sqlcontext actions, unfortunately i cant seem to find a good response to what i need. Is there a good way to get this list of objects using that? All i need is to return all the entries that have this id on their eventId column.

this is a example of what the system do, this is a function that returns one entry, but i'm not sure if it will do what i want:

```cs
public async Task<EventDate> GetById(int id)
{
  return await _sqlContext.EventDate
    .Include(x => x.Hours)
    .Include(x => x.Event)
    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

i would be grateful if someone could explain that to me a little more, i'm not so experienced in that regard and i cant seem to find any good explanations.

Edit:
Due to a request, here is the create script for the EventDate table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventDate](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdEvent] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdZoomAccount] [int] NULL,
    [Date] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Hour] [time](7) NULL,
    [Type] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Url] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MeetingType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DurationHours] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DurationMinutes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IdRoom] [int] NULL,
    [IdLocation] [int] NULL,
    [EventType] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EventDate] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventDate] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [MeetingType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventDate] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IdLocation]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventDate] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [EventType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventDate]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EventDate_MeetingLocation_IdLocation] FOREIGN KEY([IdLocation])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MeetingLocation] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventDate] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EventDate_MeetingLocation_IdLocation]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventDate]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EventDate_Event_IdEvent] FOREIGN KEY([IdEvent])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Event] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventDate] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EventDate_Event_IdEvent]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventDate]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EventDate_Rooms_IdRoom] FOREIGN KEY([IdRoom])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Rooms] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventDate] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EventDate_Rooms_IdRoom]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventDate]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_EventDate_ZoomAccount_IdZoomAccount] FOREIGN KEY([IdZoomAccount])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ZoomAccount] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EventDate] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_EventDate_ZoomAccount_IdZoomAccount]
GO
```

Comment: **Exactly** what type is `SqlContext`? Please post the full type name.

Comment: Your code looks like Entity Framework (which uses `DbContext`) but `SqlContext` is something else entirely - methinks whoever created your EF code wasn't careful with type-names...

Comment: It looks like you're using Entity Framework. `FirstOrDefaultAsync` probably isn't what you need to get a collection of objects.

Comment: You should remove the `.AsNoTracking()` line unless you have a specific good reason for using it.

Comment: As this is a `Task`-returning `async` method, the method should be renamed to `GetEventByIdAsync()` and have a `CancellationToken` parameter.

Comment: yes, that code is not mine, is what the previous dev did, this is a func that goes to the server and returns a single entry using its base id, but i dont really understand what it is doing.

Comment: `Task<List<EventDate>> GetAll() => _sqlContext.EventDate
    .Include(x => x.Hours)
    .Include(x => x.Event)
.Where(x => x.Event.Id == eventId)
    .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync()`?

Comment: @CodeCaster since i only have access to the eventId, would removing the .Include(x => x.Hours) and .Include(x => x.Event) be a thing? i also imagine i would have to chande Id to eventId.

Comment: I have updated my comment. You just appear to need `.Where(x => x.Event.Id == eventId)`, but it's really unclear.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, thank you, i am new on that area so i still don't know a lot, ill try that way and make some tests.

Comment: @H4mAdAr4 Show us your database's `CREATE TABLE` methods for your `dbo.EventDate` table. Use SSMS's "Script to..." feature.

Comment: @Dai i have added the script

Comment: @CodeCaster Your suggestion worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all that commented on my question, @CodeCaster was the one to solve my issue, all i needed to do was create a new function as follows:

```
public async Task<List<EventDate>> GetListById(int id)
{
   return await _sqlContext.EventDate
   .Where(x => x.IdEvent == id)
   .AsNoTracking()
   .ToListAsync();
}
```